# Inside function F, use an argument to F as an argument to update()

Tags: r, formula, rlang

I would like to have a function like `my_lm`, exemplified below:

```
library(rlang)

base_formula <- new_formula(lhs = quote(potato), 
                            rhs = quote(Sepal.Width + Petal.Length))

my_lm <- function(response) {
    lm(formula = update(old = base_formula, new = quote(response) ~ . ),
       data = iris)
}

my_lm(response = Sepal.Length)
```

But I am met with the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = update(old = base_formula, new = enquo(response) ~  : 
  object is not a matrix
```

I suspect I am misusing `rlang`, but I can't seem to figure out what combination of quoting, unquoting and formulating would solve this problem.

EDIT:  desired output is as if I ran:

```
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length,
```

data = iris)

EDIT2:  I should also clarify, I'm really interested in a solution that uses `rlang` to solve this problem through `update` more so than a solution that uses `paste`, `gsub`, and `formula`.

Comment: What is your expected output for my_lm?

Comment: clarified above, thanks for asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that works

```
base_formula <- new_formula(lhs = quote(potato), 
                            rhs = quote(Sepal.Width + Petal.Length))

my_lm <- function(response) {
  newf <- new_formula(get_expr(enquo(response)), quote(.))
  lm(formula = update(old = base_formula, new = newf),
     data = iris)
}

my_lm(response = Sepal.Length)
```

It seems to be a bit of a mess because quosures are also basically formulas and you're trying to make a regular formula with them. And then `new_formula` doesn't seem to allow for `!!` expansion.

If you are really just interested in changing the left hand side, something like this might be more direct

```
my_lm <- function(response) {
  newf <- base_formula
  f_lhs(newf) <- get_expr(enquo(response))
  lm(formula = get_expr(newf),
     data = iris)
}
```